# getting latest changes and updates from git server

Tags: git, git-pull

I had created my own Branch named as vishal_branch from master branch.
I had done some changes before and committed.
After me many other's also did changes and committed.
This will update the server with new changes.
Now again I am working in my local Branch (vishal_branch).

How can I get the lasted updates of server in my branch.

Comment: Isn't `git pull` working?

Comment: commit in git doesn't actually update the remote repository. You need to push the changes. Have you pushed the changes?

Comment: @RohitJain NO. Its not working as it say I have some changes to commit, But i dont want those changes done by me.. I just want latest code present in GIT SERVER..

Comment: @pratZ Before I did changes in my local repo, now somebody else have done correct changes and updates the server. I don't want my changes, I just want latest code in SERVER.

Comment: you can revert your commit. either a hard reset or revert depending on your situation, and then pull the changes.

Answer (score 3):

You have to fetch the state of origin, and merge origin/master updates into your local branch:

```
git fetch origin 
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
```

To switch to your branch, just do

```
git checkout vishal_branch
```

Comment: A.I have some changes done but haven't commit, so cant I do above steps?   As i tried this earlier but it give me error that I have some changes to commit. I don't want to commit as somebody else already had done correct changes. I want to discard my changes and want only changes present in SERVER.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do pull from source. That will bring you local branch up to the same level as the source branch. If you changed same files, merge might be necessary.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull